# JavaScript script create only one textarea instead of 4

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, text, area

```
    <div id="textfelder"></div>
<script>
if (!document.getElementById('command1')) {
    string = '<input type="text" id="command1">';
    document.getElementById("textfelder").innerHTML = string;
    }
if (!document.getElementById('command2')) {
    string = '<input type="text" id="command2">';
    document.getElementById("textfelder").innerHTML = string;
    }
if (!document.getElementById('command3')) {
     string = '<input type="text" id="command3">';
     document.getElementById("textfelder").innerHTML = string;
    }
if (!document.getElementById('command4')) {
     string = '<input type="text" id="command4">';
     document.getElementById("textfelder").innerHTML = string;
    }
</script>
```

This only creates one textarea with the ID "command4".
When I remove the last if-statement, the script will be create the textarea with the ID "command3" but the other textareas will be not created.
Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `+=` operator instead of `=`.

```
    <div id="textfelder"></div>
<script>
if (!document.getElementById('command1')) {
    string = '<input type="text" id="command1">';
    document.getElementById("textfelder").innerHTML += string;
    }
if (!document.getElementById('command2')) {
    string = '<input type="text" id="command2">';
    document.getElementById("textfelder").innerHTML += string;
    }
if (!document.getElementById('command3')) {
     string = '<input type="text" id="command3">';
     document.getElementById("textfelder").innerHTML += string;
    }
if (!document.getElementById('command4')) {
     string = '<input type="text" id="command4">';
     document.getElementById("textfelder").innerHTML += string;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using jquery, you should use `+=`

```
document.getElementById("textfelder").innerHTML += string;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code. it is overwrite content in textfielder. try below code for append it.

```
document.getElementById("textfelder").innerHTML += string;
```